# ¿Existe alguna manera de pasar de list<T> a List<List<T>> con Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

He hecho un codigo que hace lo siguiente:

```
public List<List<object>> SegmentarLista(List<object> origen, tamaño){
    resultado= new List<List<object>>();
    for (int i=0; i<origen.Length;i+tamaño){
         resultado.Add(origen.GetRange(i,tamaño))
    }

}
```

¿Existiría alguna manera de hacer esto con Linq sin el for?

edit:
La pregunta no es en búsqueda de eficiencia, ni legibilidad. Es pura curiosidad de como conseguir lo mismo de una manera mas funcional, con variables inmutables.

Comment: mas alla de que seguro que si.. la pregunta es porque?? es solo por que se vea mas bonito? o hay algo mas que estas pensando... porque si ese codigo funciona, no se porque lo querrias tocar...

Comment: ¿qué se supone debe hacer tu código, segmentar la lista en base a tamaño?

Comment: Basicamente me gustaria poder hacer estas funciones también en lenguaje funcional con variables inmutables. Y para ello lo ideal seria no tener un iterador en el for. Es más bien una pregunta para conocer como exprimir las expresiones lambda.

Comment: @shop350 si, sencillamente devuelve una listas de lista elementos del tamaño dado. El problema real era una tabla de 2 dimensiones dada en 1 array unidimensional

Comment: la pregunta es para que quieres LINQ o Lambda ? eso no los volverá mas eficientes.

Comment: @Mike es sencillamente, para conseguir funciones puras con todas las variables inmutables. Estoy intenando aprender programación funcional, y este tipo de problemas no se me ocurre como  resolverlos con variables inmutables.

Comment: Creo que la mejor forma de hacerlo es el método que ya tienes. De todas maneras, echa un vistazo a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11463734/579895), donde tienes varias alternativas

Comment: Gracias @Pikoh No sabia que select puede pasarte el indice del elemento, con eso creo que podría solucionar-lo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un ejemplo de código en el cual se divide una lista en filas de 2

```
 var vector = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
 var result= vector.Select((num, indexer) => new { Fila = indexer/2, Value = num })
            .GroupBy(item=>item.Fila)
            .Select(grp=>grp.Select(i=>i.Value).ToList())
            .ToList();
```

Quizá existe alguna manera mas elegante, pero con group by podemos hacer esta transformación de manera fácil y a nivel personal me parece un código más entendible.